# DataGridTemplateColumn as custom control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I try to make custom control based on `DataGridTemplateColumn` for using it in simple `datagrid`.

My XAML code looks:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:dgNuCol="clr-namespace:Columns.DataGridNumberColumn"
                    xmlns:nb="clr-namespace:NumberBox"  >
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type dgNuCol:DataGridNumberColumn}">
        <Setter Property="CellEditingTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dgNuCol:DataGridNumberColumn}">
                    <nb:NumberBox Text="123"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="CellTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dgNuCol:DataGridNumberColumn}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="123" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And my cs code:

```
namespace Columns.DataGridNumberColumn
{
    public partial class DataGridNumberColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
    {
    }
}
```

And I try to use it in my `datagrid`:

```
        <dgNuCol:DataGridNumberColumn Header="Values" CanUserReorder="False"/>
```

Nothing happens. There are no any changes in my `datagrid`, just empty cell. What I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I try to make it programmatically:

```
public partial class DataGridNumberColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
    {
        public DataGridNumberColumn()
        {

            FrameworkElementFactory textFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
            textFactory.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, "123");
            DataTemplate textTemplate = new DataTemplate();
            textTemplate.VisualTree = textFactory;
            this.CellTemplate = textTemplate;
        }
    }
```

But, again, no any changes in `datagrid`.

UPDATE2:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <dgNuCol:DataGridNumberColumn Header="Values" CanUserReorder="False"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Does it compile? Quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx) _you can set a style on any element that derives from `FrameworkElement` or `FrameworkContentElement`_ so it won't be valid for `DataGridTemplateColumn`

Comment: @dkozl - Thanks for the answer. Yes it compile. Can you give some more information or example, please. I don't understand how can I make it.

Comment: Updated code in question works fine for me. Can you show code of DataGrid that how you adding this column to dataGrid?

Comment: You haven't set any ItemsSource for your dataGrid?